# PHP PDOException -- Invalid parameter number: Columns/Parameters are 1-based

Tags: php, mysql, exception, pdo

My code is:

```
.....
.....

$sql = 'SELECT '.$return_fields.' FROM '.$table.' WHERE '.$search_field.'=:'.$search_field;
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam($search_field, $search_val);
$stmt->execute();

....
....
```

where `$search_field = 'reg_user_linked', $search_val = 'aa@gmail.com'`.

This error occurs when execute the statement and I couldn't figure out why:

> Invalid parameter number: Columns/Parameters are 1-based

Can anyone help?

---

After hours of trying, I found out that this error only occurs when I was in debugging mode. If I ran the code and print the result, it works.....
Does anyone know why this happens? (My IDE is NetBeans 7.2, debug tool is xdebug)...

Comment: Show your `$search_field` and `$search_val` contents. What you've shown is pretty much useless for diagnosing the problem.

Comment: I agree with @MarcB. I'd guess that `$search_field` is 0 or `'0'` or `''` or `false` or `null` - anything that is evaluated as zero to bindParam().

Comment: Thanks Guys. $search_field = 'reg_user_linked', $search_val = 'aa@gmail.com'

Comment: It's worth printing out `$sql` in your code too, temporarily, in case you've made a mistake with one of those variable names.

Comment: @halfer I pasted the sql into mysql and it works fine, of course, I replaced the binding_variable with its value.

Comment: What are the return values you get on `prepare` and `execute`? You should test both of them for `false`, in case there is an error. Do you have errors/warnings enabled?

Answer (score 6):

When binding the parameter you need to specify the `:` in the parameter name:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':' . $search_field, $search_val);
```

You are getting an error because this is missing and the code falls back to expecting an integer value to indicate the parameter position (as if you were using `?`-style parameters).

Note this description of the first parameter for `PDOStatement::bindParam()` from the documentation.

> parameter
>
> Parameter identifier. For a prepared statement using named placeholders, this will be a parameter name of the form :name. For a
>   prepared statement using question mark placeholders, this will be the
>   1-indexed position of the parameter.

Comment: This is what is wrong: he has not. It works without no colons. Although your answer won't do any harm, but it cannot solve ANYthing

Comment: @MikeBrant tried adding :, still getting the same error

Comment: @YourCommonSense Honestly, I have never tried to bind a named parameter without the colon, so would have no idea as to whether it would work or not.  The documentation is however clear on what the expected string format is.  Relying behavior which is not documented is not a good idea.

Comment: Still it is not an answer, according to your strict standards for the answers, if any

Comment: @shenjw Have you verified with `var_dump()` or similar that you do actually have the values you expect in your variables?  You also might try adding spaces around the `=` in your SQL template i.e. `WHERE ' . $search_field . ' = :' . $search_field` Not sure if that is a probelk or not, but at least it is more readable.

Comment: @YourCommonSense All answers are not going to solve the problem.  It is an answer in the sense of what StackOverflow expects.  I pointed out a specific item where I believe a problem existed in his code, I explained why I believed this to be a problem, and I offered up a solution.

Comment: @MikeBrant I am in the debugging mode, I am sure $search_val has a value. Have you ever encountered this error during your experience with PHP/PDO

Comment: @shejw I have not.  You could try `?` style parameter and do this instead `$stmt->bindParam(1, $search_val);`

Comment: @MikeBrant Thanks Mike, I tried and still not working... Have been stuck for hours....